# Getting a 404 when using the DocuSign REST API

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

In my Laravel application I am sending DocuSign envelopes with this package: https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/Laravel-Docusign which works nicely.

This application also using the "Polling" method to check for changes to envelopes.

To accomplish this I grab the envelope IDs from various different models and then pass these IDs to DocuSign's `listStatusChanges()` method which takes an amount to check and an array of envelope IDs.

If the status comes back as completed I use another method `getDocument()` to download the signed document.

Here is the job that runs every 15 minutes.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\CompanyActionPlan;
use App\CompanyOutcome;
use App\GrowthHubOutcome;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\CompanyRegistration;
use App\GrowthHubCompanyRegistration;
use App\Notifications\ActionPlanFormStatusUpdated;
use App\Notifications\GrowthHubOutcomesFormStatusUpdated;
use App\Notifications\GrowthHubRegistrationFormStatusUpdated;
use App\Notifications\OutcomesFormStatusUpdated;
use App\Notifications\RegistrationFormStatusUpdated;
use DocuSign;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;
use Log;

class PollDocuSignEnvelopes implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Create a new DocuSign client
        $client = DocuSign::create();

        // Create an empty array
        $envelopeIds = [];

        // Retrieve the unsigned envelopes from the company registrations
        $actionPlanEnvelopes = CompanyActionPlan::select('envelope_id')
            ->unsignedEnvelope()
            ->unvoidedEnvelope()
            ->pluck('envelope_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Retrieve the unsigned envelopes from the action plans
        $registrationEnvelopes = CompanyRegistration::select('envelope_id')
            ->unsignedEnvelope()
            ->unvoidedEnvelope()
            ->pluck('envelope_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Retrieve the unsigned envelopes from the outcomes
        $outcomeEnvelopes = CompanyOutcome::select('envelope_id')
            ->unsignedEnvelope()
            ->unvoidedEnvelope()
            ->pluck('envelope_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Retrieve the unsigned envelopes from the lgh outcomes
        $growthHubOutcomeEnvelopes = GrowthHubOutcome::select('envelope_id')
            ->unsignedEnvelope()
            ->unvoidedEnvelope()
            ->pluck('envelope_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Retrieve the unsigned envelopes from the lgh outcomes
        $growthHubRegistrationEnvelopes = GrowthHubCompanyRegistration::select('envelope_id')
            ->unsignedEnvelope()
            ->unvoidedEnvelope()
            ->pluck('envelope_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Merge the collection and send all envelope IDs to DocuSign for checking
        $envelopeIds = array_merge(
            $actionPlanEnvelopes,
            $registrationEnvelopes,
            $outcomeEnvelopes,
            $growthHubOutcomeEnvelopes,
            $growthHubRegistrationEnvelopes
        );

        // Only do anything if there are envelopes
        if ($envelopeIds) {
            $options = $client->envelopes->listStatusChangesOptions([
                'count' => 25,
                'envelope_ids' => $envelopeIds,
            ]);

            $changes = $client->envelopes->listStatusChanges($options);

            foreach ($changes['envelopes'] as $envelope) {
                $this->checkActionPlans($envelope, $client);
                $this->checkRegistrations($envelope, $client);
                $this->checkOutcomes($envelope, $client);
                $this->checkGrowthHubOutcomes($envelope, $client);
                $this->checkGrowthHubRegistrations($envelope, $client);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the registration forms against the returned changes from DocuSign
     *
     * @param string $envelope
     * @param mixed  $client
     *
     */
    private function checkRegistrations($envelope, $client)
    {
        $registration = CompanyRegistration::where('envelope_id', $envelope['envelope_id'])->first();

        if ($registration) {
            // Only attempt anything if that status is actually different to the previous attempt
            if ($envelope['status'] != $registration->envelope_status) {
                Log::info("SME Registration for company {$registration->company_name} was {$envelope['status']}.");

                if ($envelope['status'] == 'voided') {
                    $voidedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['voided_date_time']);
                    $registration->markAsVoided($voidedAt);
                    $registration->user->notify(new RegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the document has been declined
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'declined') {
                    $registration->markAsDeclined();
                    $registration->user->notify(new RegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the document has been delivered
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'delivered') {
                    $registration->markAsDelivered();
                    $registration->user->notify(new RegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the envelope is complete, timestamp it, notify the creator and grab the signed document
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'completed') {
                    $filePath = "/registrations/{$registration->id}/signed.pdf";

                    $this->retrieveSignedDocument($client, $registration->envelope_id, $filePath);

                    $registration->markAsCompleted(Carbon::parse($envelope['status_changed_date_time']), $filePath);

                    $registration->user->notify(new RegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the action plan forms against the returned changes from DocuSign
     *
     * @param string $envelope
     * @param mixed  $client
     *
     */
    private function checkActionPlans($envelope, $client)
    {
        $actionPlan = CompanyActionPlan::where('envelope_id', $envelope['envelope_id'])->first();

        if ($actionPlan) {
            if ($envelope['status'] != $actionPlan->envelope_status) {
                Log::info("SME Action Plan for company {$actionPlan->company_name} was {$envelope['status']}.");
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'voided') {
                    $voidedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['voided_date_time']);
                    $actionPlan->markAsVoided($voidedAt);
                    $actionPlan->user->notify(new ActionPlanFormStatusUpdated($actionPlan));
                }

                // If the document has been declined
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'declined') {
                    $actionPlan->markAsDeclined();
                    $actionPlan->user->notify(new ActionPlanFormStatusUpdated($actionPlan));
                }

                // If the document has been delivered
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'delivered') {
                    $actionPlan->markAsDelivered();
                }

                // If the envelope is complete, timestamp it, notify the creator and grab the signed document
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'completed') {
                    $completedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['status_changed_date_time']);

                    $filePath = "/action-plans/{$actionPlan->id}/signed.pdf";

                    $signedDocument = $client->envelopes->getDocument(1, $actionPlan->envelope_id);

                    $documentContents = file_get_contents($signedDocument->getPathname());

                    Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, $documentContents);

                    $actionPlan->markAsCompleted($completedAt, $filePath);

                    $actionPlan->user->notify(new ActionPlanFormStatusUpdated($actionPlan));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the registration forms against the returned changes from DocuSign
     *
     * @param string $envelope
     * @param mixed  $client
     *
     */
    private function checkOutcomes($envelope, $client)
    {
        $outcome = CompanyOutcome::where('envelope_id', $envelope['envelope_id'])->first();

        if ($outcome) {
            if ($envelope['status'] != $outcome->envelope_status) {
                Log::info("SME Outcomes for company {$outcome->company_name} was {$envelope['status']}.");

                if ($envelope['status'] == 'voided') {
                    $voidedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['voided_date_time']);
                    $outcome->markAsVoided($voidedAt);
                    $outcome->user->notify(new OutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the document has been declined
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'declined') {
                    $outcome->markAsDeclined();
                    $outcome->user->notify(new OutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the document has been delivered
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'delivered') {
                    $outcome->markAsDelivered();
                    $outcome->user->notify(new OutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the envelope is complete, timestamp it, notify the creator and grab the signed document
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'completed') {
                    $filePath = "/outcomes/{$outcome->id}/signed.pdf";

                    $this->retrieveSignedDocument($client, $outcome->envelope_id, $filePath);

                    $outcome->markAsCompleted(Carbon::parse($envelope['status_changed_date_time']), $filePath);

                    $outcome->user->notify(new OutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the lgh outcomes forms against the returned changes from DocuSign
     *
     * @param string $envelope
     * @param mixed  $client
     *
     */
    private function checkGrowthHubOutcomes($envelope, $client)
    {
        $outcome = GrowthHubOutcome::where('envelope_id', $envelope['envelope_id'])->first();

        if ($outcome) {
            if ($envelope['status'] != $outcome->envelope_status) {
                Log::info("LGH SME Outcomes for company {$outcome->company_name} was {$envelope['status']}.");

                if ($envelope['status'] == 'voided') {
                    $voidedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['voided_date_time']);
                    $outcome->markAsVoided($voidedAt);
                    $outcome->user->notify(new GrowthHubOutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the document has been declined
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'declined') {
                    $outcome->markAsDeclined();
                    $outcome->user->notify(new GrowthHubOutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the document has been delivered
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'delivered') {
                    $outcome->markAsDelivered();
                    $outcome->user->notify(new GrowthHubOutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }

                // If the envelope is complete, timestamp it, notify the creator and grab the signed document
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'completed') {
                    $filePath = "/outcomes/growth-hub/{$outcome->id}/signed.pdf";

                    $this->retrieveSignedDocument($client, $outcome->envelope_id, $filePath);

                    $outcome->markAsCompleted(Carbon::parse($envelope['status_changed_date_time']), $filePath);

                    $outcome->user->notify(new GrowthHubOutcomesFormStatusUpdated($outcome));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the lgh outcomes forms against the returned changes from DocuSign
     *
     * @param string $envelope
     * @param mixed  $client
     *
     */
    private function checkGrowthHubRegistrations($envelope, $client)
    {
        $registration = GrowthHubCompanyRegistration::where('envelope_id', $envelope['envelope_id'])->first();

        if ($registration) {
            if ($envelope['status'] != $registration->envelope_status) {
                Log::info("LGH SME Registration for company {$registration->company_name} was {$envelope['status']}.");

                if ($envelope['status'] == 'voided') {
                    $voidedAt = Carbon::parse($envelope['voided_date_time']);
                    $registration->markAsVoided($voidedAt);
                    $registration->user->notify(new GrowthHubRegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the document has been declined
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'declined') {
                    $registration->markAsDeclined();
                    $registration->user->notify(new GrowthHubRegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the document has been delivered
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'delivered') {
                    $registration->markAsDelivered();
                    $registration->user->notify(new GrowthHubRegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }

                // If the envelope is complete, timestamp it, notify the creator and grab the signed document
                if ($envelope['status'] == 'completed') {
                    $filePath = "/registrations/growth-hub/{$registration->id}/signed.pdf";

                    $this->retrieveSignedDocument($client, $registration->envelope_id, $filePath);

                    $registration->markAsCompleted(Carbon::parse($envelope['status_changed_date_time']), $filePath);

                    $registration->user->notify(new GrowthHubRegistrationFormStatusUpdated($registration));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the signed document from DocuSign and save it to storage at the given file path.
     *
     * @param [type] $client
     * @param string $envelopeId
     * @param string $filePath
     */
    private function retrieveSignedDocument($client, $envelopeId, $filePath)
    {
        $signedDocument = $client->envelopes->getDocument(1, $envelopeId);

        $documentContents = file_get_contents($signedDocument->getPathname());

        Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, $documentContents);
    }
}
```

Very recently, as in today, I've started receiving a 404 from the API.

This is the stack trace.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
<h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{"url":"https://advice.newable.io","input":[],"userId":null,"email":null,"exception":"[object] (DocuSign\\eSign\\Client\\ApiException(code: 404): Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [404] with response Body: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type=\"text/css\">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id=\"content\">
<div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>
<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
<h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
at /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Client/ApiClient.php:330)
[stacktrace]
#0 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php(9328): DocuSign\\eSign\\Client\\ApiClient->callApi('/v2/accounts/50...', 'GET', Array, '', Array, '\\\\DocuSign\\\\eSign...', '/v2/accounts/{a...')
#1 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php(9208): DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi->listStatusChangesWithHttpInfo('509375162', Object(DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi\\ListStatusChangesOptions))
#2 [internal function]: DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi->listStatusChanges('509375162', Object(DocuSign\\eSign\\Api\\EnvelopesApi\\ListStatusChangesOptions))
#3 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/tucker-eric/docusign-rest-client/src/Api/BaseApi.php(76): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/app/Jobs/PollDocuSignEnvelopes.php(107): DocuSign\\Rest\\Api\\BaseApi->__call('listStatusChang...', Array)
#5 [internal function]: App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes->handle()
#6 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#8 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#9 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(590): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#11 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#12 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes))
#13 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes))
#14 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(83): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes), false)
#16 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes))
#17 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes))
#18 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(85): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(59): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(App\\Jobs\\PollDocuSignEnvelopes))
#20 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(88): Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Array)
#21 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(368): Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\Job->fire()
#22 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(314): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#23 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(134): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#24 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(112): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#25 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(96): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#27 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#29 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#30 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#31 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(590): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#32 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#33 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#34 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#35 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1005): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(271): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(147): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#38 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#40 /homepages/45/d641872465/htdocs/sites/ita-portal/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#41 {main}
"}
```

How can I debug this?

(I have an identical setup in a DocuSign Sandox and it works as expected).

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'll say you may have reached your hourly API limit. Polling is not a recommended approach. 
If this still happens at the top of the hour, you may want to provide API logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I'm aware of that this call in particular returns a 404 response is if the request includes a specific list of envelopeIds over a certain number. The older versions of our SDKs and a lot of customer solutions add these envelopeIds to the request in the form of URL Parameters. I found when testing this that when I approached or went over ~49 envelopes the response changed from a 200 to a 404.

Looking at the provided code I see this:

```
// Only do anything if there are envelopes
if ($envelopeIds) {
    $options = $client->envelopes->listStatusChangesOptions([
        'count' => 25,
        'envelope_ids' => $envelopeIds,
    ]);

$changes = $client->envelopes->listStatusChanges($options);
```

Can you confirm the total number of envelopes being included here? If the number is ~49 that is likely the culprit, meaning you'll need to add in an extra check to limit the total number of envelopeIds being passed into the listStatusChangesOptions object.

Comment: Do you think this is not mentioned in the API because it should be a given?

Comment: That's a fair question. My understanding is that the URL length should typically be limited to ~2000 (2048) characters, as this is the default for some web browsers. IE for example has a default limit of 2048. Looking here on SO I found this very solid explanation on the standards for URL limits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers